# In Jess, how would I add a slot to a template through a rule?

Tags: jess

As an example, I have:

```
(deftemplate Animal
(slot has-feathers (default FALSE))
(slot name (default "George"))
)
```

and in a rule I have:

```
(defrule bird-test
?a <-(Animal (has-feathers ?))
=>
(printout t ?a.name " is a bird" crlf)
"Add slot 'bird' to ?a or Animal"
)
```

How would I do this? and thank you in advance

Edit: Thanks guys! I think I understand what I need to do.

Comment: Can you please add a 2 or 3 sentence text description of what you are trying to do? Simply listing code and then "How would I do this?" does not give us enough information to help you.

Comment: If you can read the code, the question is actually pretty clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Ernest's proposal of providing the slot up front, you might also consider a multislot which can act as a container for all sorts of properties your rules might detect for an Animal.

```
(deftemplate Animal
    (slot name)
    (slot has-feathers)
    (multislot props)...)
```

You can write the

```
(defrule bird-test
  (declare (no-loop TRUE))
  ?a <-(Animal (has-feathers TRUE)(props $?ex ))
=>
  (modify ?a (props $?ex isBird))
  (printout t ?a.name "'s props: " ?a.props crlf)
)
```

Alternatively, a very general kind of deftemplate can be used to express all kinds or properties dynamically:

```
(deftemplate is-a
    (slot thing)
    (slot property))
```

But this goes beyond a mere answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add slots to templates after they're defined; that would be analogous to adding a member variable to a Java class while your program runs.

But you can *set* the value of an existing slot; if your template had a `kind` slot, you could say

```
(modify ?a (kind bird))
```